# Footer floating to the top even though used CSS listed here

Tags: html, css

I have tried all of the CSS listed on this site and others and cannot get a footer on my page to appear at the bottom...right now it's floating in the top half of the page.  Below is my CSS; it may have a lot of extra stuff because I've tried everything, and this is my first site.

See: [www.medsocialgroup.com](http://www.medsocialgroup.com)

Thank you!

**CSS**

```
<!-- language: lang-css -->

body {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #FFF;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    color: #333;
    background-image: url(dropshadow.jpg);
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    background-position: center center;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:100%;
}

div.wrapper
{
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top:20px;
    width:790px;
    min-height:100%; 
    height:auto
    height: 100%
    background-color: #FFF;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
}
#medcommunity{
    font-size:36px;
    color: #999;
    }
#left_column{
    float:left;
    margin-left:0px;
    width:390px;
    height:420px;
    border-right-width: thin;
    border-right-style: double;
    border-right-color: #CCC;

}
#logo{
    float:left;
    clear:left;
    margin-top:100px;
    margin-left:0px;
}

#right_column{
    float:right;
    padding:0;
    width:385px;
    height:420px;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    color: #333;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-align: left;


}
#webtext{
    margin-top:75px;
    font-size: 20px;
}

#menu{
    background-color:#CCC;
    width:100%;
    height:40px;
    margin-top:50px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: lighter;
    text-align: center;
    background-position: center center;
    color: #FFF;
}

#footer{
    background-color:#CCC;
    width: 100%;
    height:50px;
    color: #CCC;
    border-top-width: thin;
    border-top-style: double;
    border-top-color: #999;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: @jennifer your footer is outside your wrapper div, did you want it that way?  Also, it appears in the middle because your sidebar divs are floating, so they're not in the document flow to push the footer down.  I like the look of your webpage by the way, it looks nice :)

Comment: You want [`position: fixed`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#fixed-positioning) on your `#footer`.

Comment: @mu is too short: that makes the footer disappear completely, at least in Firefox 5...

Comment: @jennifer when I said sidebar divs, what I meant were your column divs, inside the wrapper.

Comment: Keoki-what do you suggest for mu? thank you! and what's your suggestion for fixing the sidebar/column divs? thank you!

Comment: You need to add `left` and `bottom` attributes as well. Fixed positioning positions an element at an specific position relative to the browser viewport but you still have to tell it where.

Comment: @jennifer sorry I'm kind of stuck on what to do next, I don't know why the footer still won't go all the way down, but the `clear:both;` rule for the footer div is definitely a step in the right direction. I recommend you try taking a look a the [Twenty Eleven](http://twentyelevendemo.wordpress.com/) and [Mystique](http://mystiquedemo.wordpress.com/) themes to see how they do it.  Both their footer divs also use the `clear:both;` rule so that they don't occupy the same space as the floating columns. Good luck!

Comment: @jennifer I have a new solution for you, try it out and let us know if it works for you.

Comment: @mu is too short: I tried specifying left and bottom with position fixed, but the footer is now stuck to the bottom of the browser viewport, I don't think that's correct, is it?

Comment: @Keoki: That's what fixed positioning does but that may not be exactly what jennifer is looking for; "bottom" could mean "bottom of the content" or "bottom of the browser".

Comment: @jennifer what tools are you using to develop your web pages?  Are you using Firefox Firebug, or any similar tools like in IE 9, Chrome, and Opera (I guess Safari should have some similar developer tools too)?

Answer (score 1):

If you use `clear:both;` on the footer div, that will help push the footer to the bottom, but it still won't go all the way down for some reason, I don't know why.

Also, if you use the following rules instead of the `clear:both;` that I suggested above,

```
#footer {
    background-color: #CCCCCC;
    border-top: thin double #999999;
    color: #CCCCCC;
    height: 50px;

    /* Try these new ones */
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
```

The footer seems to drop to the bottom okay.  But this only works in Firefox 5, I tried it in Chrome and it didn't work there.  I tried `position: fixed;` like @mu suggested in Chrome and Firefox 5, and it sort of works, you have to specify `width: 100%` though.  The problem with this is that the footer is fixed to the bottom of the browser viewport, so if you resize the browser and make the window shorter, the footer travels with the bottom edge of the viewport, which I don't think you want.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Ryan Fait's Sticky Footer](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/), I came up with this:

http://jfcoder.com/test/medsocial.html

These are styles I added or altered:

```
/* Sticky Footer by Ryan Fait http://ryanfait.com/ */
* {
  margin: 0;
}
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  height: auto !important;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto -39px; /* the bottom margin is the negative value of the footer's height */
}
#footer, .push {
  height: 39px; /* .push must be the same height as #footer */
  clear: both;
}
/* Other styles that help fix the top */
.wrapper {
  margin-top: 0 !important;
}
#menu {
  background-color:#fff;
  margin-top: 0;
  padding-top: 50px;
}
#menu div {
  background-color:#CCC;
  width:100%;
  height:40px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: lighter;
  text-align: center;
  background-position: center center;
  color: #FFF;
}
#medcommunity {
  margin-top: 55px;
}
```

And the markup (note the `DIV#push` that was added):

```
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
 <div id="menu"><div>HOME | HOW IT WORKS | SERVICES | CONTACT US</div></div>
 <div id="medcommunity"><p>medical + community</p></div>
 <div id="left_column"><img src="msgrouptransp.png" id="logo" width="325" height="120" alt="medsocial" /></div>
 <div id="right_column">
  <p id="webtext">Social Media Solutions  for the Medical Community</p>
  <p>We help Hospitals,  Medical Groups, Physicians, and more to connect with their communities via  Facebook, Twitter, and other social media sites.  </p>
  <p>Find out <u>How it Works</u>.</p>
 </div>
 <div class="push"></div>
</div>
<div id="footer"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Jared--thank you for your help--it looks great on your site, but i think i made all of your recommended changes and it didn't work for me...?

Comment: @Jennifer - Where did you make them? When I click your link, the css and markup are the same.

Comment: @Jennifer - The way that the Sticky Footer works is to give the HTML and BODY tags a 100% height, then using a placeholder (`DIV#push`) and a negative margin, put the footer at the bottom of the wrapper DIV, which is now at 100% height as well. You need to change some of your other markup and styles to compensate, but it should work without issue if you understand what its doing.

Comment: I'm editing on my dreamweaver files...if you can copy and paste the entire css you used to make it work i could copy it into my css...?

Comment: @Jennifer - I'm not following the last comment. Are you wanting me to do something? Are you editing in code view?

Comment: @Jennifer - Everything I did is in my answer. Click the link to my site and right-click, view source and you'll see I didn't copy your whole CSS. That's what the BASE element is for, it uses your own unless I hardlink to another.

Comment: @Jennifer - Also, be sure and read through the accompanying tutorial to Ryan's technique: http://ryanfait.com/resources/footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page/